# Как открыть в visual studio решение для UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Когда я открываю решение для `UWP` в `visual studia` то у меня выскакивает такой вот диалог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что установлено в данном случае:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установлена 2015 студия. Поставить студию 2017 возможности нет.Что нужно доставить и самое главное откуда чтобы студия открыла?

UDP: установка любой из SDK ссылки на которые идут с этой страницы:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive
ведут к предложению обновить студию до 2017.

Что показывает менеджер студии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установи UWP SDK

Comment: Ок, какую версию и откуда? Если поставить любую из последних то студия предлагает поставить 17-ю студию и все.

Comment: Попробуй установить WIn10 Dev Tools http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/F/C/6FC19DBF-C223-41D0-835A-BD2155BC950D/VSToolsForWindows1C.exe

Comment: Непомогло особо, я там обновил вопрос.

Comment: Попробуй:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733621/visual-studio-update-required-but-its-up-to-date или 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170002/visual-studio-update-required-sdk-is-installed